# How to get the name of the most recent folder?

Tags: batch-file

I'd like to write a batch script that is able to get the name of the most recent folder (not file) inside the current folder.
My first idea was to make a ls with the date sort option, then append the ls inside a text file and then in a string variable to at last truncate it but i am sure it's possible to do easier..!
Thanks you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember that directory names may contain space characters. Be sure to quote THE_DIR whenever it is used.

```
FOR /F "usebackq tokens=*" %%d IN (`DIR /AD /OD /B`) DO (
    SET THE_DIR=%%d
)
ECHO THE_DIR is "%THE_DIR%"
```

Comment: Well done, and totally, didn't think about it ! (not a script dude)